# Palindrome using args; help me find the error?

Tags: java, string, palindrome, args

I am building a class that checks if the input contains palindromes and returns only the palindrome terms if they exist. I have been able to develop the following, and it compiles and runs without errors, but I am not getting any return from it.

Can anyone spot where my error lies?

```
public class Palindrome {

public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {

    String back = word.charAt(word.length() - 1) + "";
    for (int i = word.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        back = back + word.charAt(i);
    }
    if (word == back) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (isPalindrome(args[i]) == true) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }

}

}
```

I believe the issue lies in the main method, specifically within the if statement, but I'm not exactly sure why it's not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (isPalindrome(args[i]) == true) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help offered. I appreciate your time!

Comment: You can check for palindromes much more efficiently by doing it in place. But that's another question. The big O of this implementation is actually n^2.

Answer (score 1):

Seconded on the .equals() error.

Also, you can easily check for palindromes by using the built-in String reversal procedure:

```
String a = "sampleelpmas";
String b = new StringBuffer(a).reverse().toString();

a.equals(b); //TRUE
```

Comment: The output is false. It is not a palindrome.

Comment: hahaha. You're right. Editing for anti-foolishness.

Comment: Now the output is correct ;).

Comment: This is why Pair Programming is the best! ;D

Comment: Pair programming is pretty good. But if we compare personal programming with pair, we compare time spent, number of errors, then conclusion would be in my opinion: programming by one person is better for employer:(, even if number of errors is less. Only one person gets payment.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you could reverse it using `back = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString()`, which is cleaner code and also more optimized (also faster but doesn't matter here).

But your problem is at comparing strings, == check if both objects are equal and this is never true for 2 strings, even if they're the same like you were expecting. Use `word.equals(back)`, which check if text contents of string match.

Answer (score 0):

Common error. Comparison of string is wrong. Do not use `==` operator. Use `equals()` method.

Change `word == back` to `word.equals(back)`.

Rest should be right.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use == to evaluate String equality, use equals() instead.

```
if (word.equals(back))
```